# What are the top 5 bloodiest battles in terms of British casualties?

Tags: war, united-kingdom, britain, battle

I have done a bit of research and it seems the Somme, Towton and maybe Bannockburn are up there? Any more to throw into the mix?

Great site by the way!

Comment: You would probably have to add Marston Moor and Flodden to the Somme, Towton and Bannockburn.

Comment: How can I forget Flodden! I am a Scot as well! Thanks. Flodden was around 20,000 casualties if I can remember my school days correctly?

Comment: Despite historical importance, the bloodiest medieval battles are tiny compared with a few days casualties of any World War.

Comment: @Pere I think we can limit that to World War I. The [total British KIA during World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties) is estimated at 383,700, and there are at least 3 battles during the first war with comparable British casualties.

Comment: @Pere possibly not when you conisder relative sizes of the forces involved, and the population at the time and the effects of those loss on that population.

Answer (score 2):

**List of battles by casualties**

I have made a list using this wikipedia article named [List of battles by casualties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_by_casualties) and have simply removed the ones involving Brits and put them in to order from one to five, and added one extra.

**One to five**

1. [Battle of the Somme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Somme). 1 July 1916 – 18 November 1916. [420,000 British casualties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Somme)
2. [Spring offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Offensive).  21 March – 18 July 1918.  [418,374](http://htthttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Offensiveps://) British casualties.
3. [Battle of Passchendaele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Passchendaele#Casualties). 31 July – 10 November 1917. [Approx 300,000 British
   casualties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Passchendaele#Casualties)
4. [Battle of Watling street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeat_of_Boudica). 61 AD. [80,000](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310071630/http://www.search.com/reference/Battle_of_Watling_Street) British casualties.
5. [Burma campaign](http://htthttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma_campaignps://). 14 December 1941 – 13 September 1945. [28,878 British killed and missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma_campaign).
6. [Battle of Towton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Towton). 29 March 1461. [28,000 disputed casualties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Towton#Rout)

Answer (score -2):

You might want to consider following battles as bloodiest for British armies. Please note I am not considering a day-by-day casualties count, but the total casualties for a battle.

- The Somme battle: classic, you cite that one already. A long and bloody battle, with I think some top day by day casualties count
- Battle of Ypres (WW1 as well)
- German Michael offensive on British forces
- Battle of Lys, a few days after the Michael offensive
- Battle of Normandy: long and blooy battle, because the British forces, as well as Commonwealth forces, handled so much offensives against German forces
- Market Garden operation (Arnhem battle) : heavy losses on airborne and armoured forces

Some good candidates:

- I suspect the Pedestal operation has suffered very high casualties, considering the high number of sunk ships and the inhability to control the battlefield after the fight
- Battle of Gandamak, 1st war of Afghanistan: a good candidate for the Asiatic zone, with 15 000 casualties including about 4 500 soldiers.
- 1917 year of air battles: a very hard year for the Royal Air Force, with numerous losses. A lot of deaths for air forces, but not as a number
- Raid on Nuremberg: A lot of deaths for air forces, but not as a number

Comment: Wild guesses are not appreciated.  Operation Pedestal, for example, has a high estimate of 550 killed -- barely a skirmish by World War I standards.